# How to write workspace resource IFolder to disk (Eclipse RCP)?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, workspace

Inside my `Perspective` class I have created myproject with the following code;

```
private void createProject() throws CoreException {

        myWorkspaceRoot = ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace().getRoot();

        myProject = myWorkspaceRoot.getProject("my");

        if( !myProject.exists() ) {
            myProject.create(null);
        }

        if(!myProject.isOpen() ) {
            myProject.open(null);
        }

        imagesFolder = myProject.getFolder("images");
        if (!imagesFolder.exists()) {
            imagesFolder.create(false, false, null);

        }


        fontsFolder = myProject.getFolder("fonts");

        if (!fontsFolder.exists()) {
            fontsFolder.create(false, false, null);
        }


    }
```

Actually, in the filesystem, the project directory was created, but fonts and images directory were not.

How to flush workspace to disk or how to do some other operation so that actual folder appear on the filesystem?

Comment: Look at other callers of IFolder#create() and IProject#create() and compare the parameters they're sending versus what you are using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second parameter of `IFolder.create` is the `local` flag which says that the folder is in the local file system - you are specifying `false` so the part of the code which creates the local folder is not called. Use

```
IFolder.create(false, true, null);
```